# ESP8266 not connecting to another ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I try to connect a few ESP8266 (STA-Mode) to one ESP8266 (AP Mode)

All of the ESP Stations connect well, but one will not connect.
The one can connect to other networks.

Debug Serial off well connecting ESPs:

```
15:03:31.355 -> fpm close 3 
15:03:31.355 -> mode : sta(c8:c9:a3:57:c7:2e)
15:03:31.402 -> add if0
15:03:31.402 -> ..scandone
15:03:33.605 -> scandone
15:03:34.492 -> state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
15:03:34.492 -> state: 2 -> 3 (0)
15:03:34.492 -> state: 3 -> 5 (10)
15:03:34.492 -> add 0
15:03:34.492 -> aid 1
15:03:34.539 -> cnt 
15:03:34.539 -> 
15:03:34.539 -> connected with cardReaderConfig, channel 1
15:03:34.539 -> dhcp client start...
15:03:34.727 -> ip:10.10.10.101,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:10.10.10.1
15:03:34.727 -> WL-CONNECTED[HTTP] begin...
```

---

Debug Serial when I try to connect the one, which is failing:

```
15:28:39.458 -> fpm close 3 
15:28:39.458 -> mode : sta(bc:ff:4d:f9:91:12)
15:28:39.458 -> add if0
15:28:39.458 -> ..scandone
15:28:43.785 -> scandone
15:28:43.785 -> no cardReaderConfig found, reconnect after 1s
15:28:43.926 -> reconnect
15:28:46.063 -> scandone
15:28:46.954 -> state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
15:28:46.954 -> state: 2 -> 3 (0)
15:28:46.954 -> state: 3 -> 5 (10)
15:28:46.954 -> add 0
15:28:46.954 -> aid 1
15:28:46.954 -> cnt 
15:28:47.970 -> ..state: 5 -> 0 (0)
15:28:47.970 -> rm 0
15:28:50.176 -> scandone
15:28:52.353 -> scandone
15:28:52.353 -> no cardReaderConfig found, reconnect after 1s
15:28:52.446 -> reconnect
15:28:54.639 -> scandone
15:28:54.639 -> no cardReaderConfig found, reconnect after 1s
15:28:54.733 -> reconnect
15:28:56.136 -> ..scandone
15:28:58.347 -> scandone
15:29:00.531 -> scandone
15:29:00.531 -> no cardReaderConfig found, reconnect after 1s
15:29:00.612 -> reconnect
15:29:02.802 -> scandone
15:29:03.688 -> state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
15:29:03.688 -> state: 2 -> 3 (0)
15:29:03.688 -> state: 3 -> 5 (10)
15:29:03.688 -> add 0
15:29:03.688 -> aid 1
15:29:03.688 -> cnt 
15:29:04.670 -> ..state: 5 -> 0 (0)
15:29:04.670 -> rm 0
```

---

When I try to connect to other networks, it works:

```
15:09:50.008 -> fpm close 3 
15:09:50.008 -> mode : sta(bc:ff:4d:f9:91:12)
15:09:50.008 -> add if0
15:09:50.008 -> ..scandone
15:09:52.252 -> scandone
15:09:53.139 -> state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
15:09:53.139 -> state: 2 -> 3 (0)
15:09:53.139 -> state: 3 -> 5 (10)
15:09:53.139 -> add 0
15:09:53.139 -> aid 5
15:09:53.139 -> cnt 
15:09:53.186 -> 
15:09:53.186 -> connected with WLAN-AF, channel 6
15:09:53.186 -> dhcp client start...
15:09:53.232 -> ip:192.168.178.94,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.178.1
15:09:53.232 -> WL-CONNECTED[HTTP] begin...
```

Hope anyone can help, but assuming this is a hardware problem...

EDIT: I can connect via normal ESP8266Wifi (Wifi Client example script)
But get the error when trying via WifiMulti or Enterprise (BasicHttpClient example script).

Comment: Any idea where "no cardReaderConfig found" is coming from?

Comment: "cardReaderConfig" is the Network SSID, a bit confusing here I see;
So sometimes it even can't find the network, but the ESPs are next to each other.

Comment: Oh right, I now see it in the first block. Do you know the MAC address of the `cardReaderConfig` AP? I wonder it if might be the same as the failing ESP (`bc:ff:4d:f9:91:12`).

Comment: I can connect when not using WifiMulti (see edit in post)

Comment: The state changes are interesting: "IDLE (0) > SCAN COMPLETED (2) > CONNECTED (3) > CONNECTION LOST (5)". But only in the failing case it goes back to IDLE, the others connect okay (even though the last state is "CONNECTION LOST"). Puzzling.